# is it run the webtours server of load runner without install load runner?

Tags: jmeter

I have to use webtours server of load runner,is it possible to use without install the load runner tool in system?

```
                          (or)
```

is there any other possibility to practice the jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do practice using blazemeter practice URL:-http://www.blazedemo.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install any open source tool you wish to use for testing purposes.  A popular item to download and use for education purposes is SugarCRM.

To your greater question, could you install just the web server alone.  Yes.  You should call HP support and ask them how.   I would recommend not telling them you are going to use it for JMETER training.

Since you are coming from LoadRunner to JMETER, you may find this online blog by Rebecca Clinard interesting

http://performanceengineeringwisdom.com/a-jmeter-rant-from-a-professed-performance-snob/